# Trouble with Carousel images in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm relatively new to Django and a complete beginner in Wagtail.

The website I am building only has one carousel and it is on the homepage. I have created the following two models in `models.py`:

```
class CarouselItem(Orderable):
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    page = ParentalKey('HomePage', related_name='carousel_items')

    panels = [
    ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]

class HomePage(Page):
    nila_intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
            InlinePanel('carousel_items', label="Carousel Items"),
            FieldPanel('nila_intro', classname="full"),
        ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Homepage"
```

In order to get the template tags right I referred to the Wagtail Demo site on Github to try and replicate what has already been done.

Basic operations such as `{% if page.carousel_items %}`, `{% for carousel_item in page.carousel_items.all %}` and `{{ carousel_item.caption }}` work just fine. Also in the admin everything is exactly as I intended.

I am however having issues getting the images and/or image `src` url's to show. I have tried both adding the following to the `src` and nothing happened: {{ carousel_item.image.url }} and then I tried removing the `<img>` tag altogether and doing a `{% image carousel_item.image alt="Slide Image" %}` it gave me an error. So I'm not really sure what to do!

I have included `{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}`

Maybe I'm not 100% clear on how ModelClusters work yet? As I saw you guys have managed carousels differently on your demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10/topics/images.html, you need to specify a resize rule such as `max-800x600` on the `{% image %}` tag to specify how the image should be resized when inserted into the template. If you don't want the image to be resized at all, use `original`:

```
{% image carousel_item.image original alt="Slide Image" %}
```

Comment: Dang, how did I miss that?!?! Thanks!   
As for the way I set the carousel  models up, there's nothing inherently wrong it? I've just got a nagging feeling there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

As another wagtail learner,  Gasman's answer looks correct and the docs cover image use pretty well.   Also your model looks fine or at least similar to ours.

For me,  I needed to use the 'as' syntax to create a manual image tag to avoid the "width" and "height" attributes that seemed to mess with some image responsiveness in the carousel.  That is:

```
{% image theme.card_image fill-262x344 as photo %}
<img src="{{ photo.url }}" alt="" class="carousel-img"/>
```