# multiple items in wagtail carousel

Tags: django-templates, slider, wagtail, django-2.0

I want to have 4 different items in a slider(Product Name section). And in the next slider, again 4 items. How to achieve this in wagtail?
Below I have given screenshot how it should be.

Screenshot:
[image]

This one is in static, but I want it dynamic. For every 4 item, it should create one slider and so on.

Comment: Use a streamfield http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html add a listblock, structblock pagechooserblock and imageblock.

Comment: this question seems relevant to yours, you can get help from this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898676/trouble-with-carousel-images-in-wagtail